# Do furious and greater magic weapon stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, weapons

It is clear that the enhancement bonus from [greater magic weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-weapon/) does not stack with a magic weapon's inherent enhancement bonus.
But how about the increase to a weapon's enhancement bonus given by a [furious weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/furious/) when it's wielder rages?

When a caster with a CL of 12 casts greater magic weapon on a +1 furious weapon for a +3 enhancement bonus and after that the wielder rages what is the weapon's enhancement bonus? 3 or 5?

Comment: The answer to this should bare in mind that under the [rules for magic weapons] (http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons) "A single weapon cannot have a modified bonus (enhancement bonus plus special ability bonus equivalents, including those from character abilities and spells) higher than +10." and that "Magic weapons have enhancement bonuses ranging from +1 to +5."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9qd9), certain effects can increase the enhancement bonus past their initial value, like the *Bane* weapon property:

> **Weapon Bonuses: Can weapon special abilities (such as bane) or class abilities (such as a paladin's divine bond) allow you to exceed the +5 enhancement bonus limit and the +10 bonus-equivalent limitation?**
>
> For the enhancement bonus limitation, it depends on the specific effect or ability that's altering the weapon.
>
> Bane: This allows the weapon to exceed the +5 limit, but only against the designated creature type. For example, **a +5 dragon-bane longsword is normally a +5 weapon, but has a +7 enhancement bonus against dragons** and deals +2d6 points of damage against dragons.
>
> Paladin: The divine bond ability says "These [enhancement] bonuses can be added to the weapon, stacking with existing weapon bonuses to a maximum of +5." That means if a paladin has a +5 longsword, she can't use her divine bond to increate the enhancement bonus to +6 or higher (but she could use her bonuses to add abilities such as flaming to the weapon).
>
> The +10 bonus-equivalent limitation is a hard cap for all weapons; you can't exceed that even with class abilities or other unusual abilities.

If we read this with that explanation in mind, what is *normal* for Furious is the enhancement bonus while not raging. And thus, this additional bonus is stacking on top of the non-raging bonus.

> When the wielder is raging or under the effect of a rage spell, the weapon’s enhancement bonus is +2 better than normal.

According to [the restrictions](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/weapons.html) on the enhancement bonus for magic weapons found on the 4th printing of the *core rulebook* (post errata), we have:

> A single weapon cannot have a modified bonus (**enhancement bonus plus special ability bonus equivalents**, including those from character abilities and spells) higher than +10.

This is a **special bonus** and works similarly to how *Bane* works, except that the condition isn't the target's creature type, but the attacker's raging status (on/off). As such, this should fall into the same situation as the Bane property described on the FAQ and on [this post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kjpr&page=1?Bane-weapons#3) from 2010 (also pre-errata) by [James Jacobs](http://paizo.com/people/JamesJacobs) (Paizo's Creative Director).

That said, a +1 longsword that is affected by *Greater Magic Weapon* should have an *enhancement bonus* of +3, which should have a *modified enhancement bonus* of +5 while the user is raging.